# Unable to set the memory limit for image OS in VMWare WorkStation

Tags: vmware-workstation

I am running Windows Server 2003 image OS on my Windows XP machine, using VMWare Workstation. But it seems that I can't set the memory limit:

[http://lh6.ggpht.com/_SDci0Pf3tzU/Skm7ur-uuNI/AAAAAAAAE_U/71kRvZC9Olc/s400/vmware..png](http://picasaweb.google.com/lh/photo/l9-98vbeRiaHiOUyDKUjKA?feat=embedwebsite)

How do I set the memory limit?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Power off the Virtual Machine to make those changes. You can't hot-add Processors or Memory in VMware Workstation.